# drupal reinstalled locally, URLs such as "admin" get page not found

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-rewrite, wamp

I've just downloaded my drupal site.

I can view the home page and the content seems to be read from the db. However i can't get to

http://localhost:81/admin or http://localhost:81/aboutus

I have enabled "mod_rewrite"

i can view content such as "?q=node/266"

I've setup virtual host

ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mySite/"

Answer (score 5):

It's your apache config. I run into this problem all the time on fresh apache installs. If you open your apache.conf or virtual host conf file you'll need to change AllowOverrides in your < Directory > from none to all for example.

`<Directory />

    Options Includes

    AllowOverride All

</Directory>`

Answer (score 3):

Try going to http://localhost:81/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls and see if Clean URLs is enabled or disabled. If disabled, try enabling, and if you can't, then chances are you'll have to edit your .htaccess and uncomment the

`# RewriteBase /`

...line or the...

`# RewriteBase /drupal`

line (changing the last one from /drupal to /mySite).

If you're still having trouble, try going through the [handbook guide to Clean URLs](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls).

Comment: It might be enabled right now so be sure to disable it or the links on your site will always return 404 until you can get the .htaccess figured out.  Also, you might be missing a .htaccess file as sometimes when copying the contents of a directory over something like WinSCP, they get left out.

Comment: thanks mike, i'm working locally, i don't have an htaccess file.  i can't get to "http://localhost:81/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls" it just 404's.

Comment: to expand, http://localhost:81/?q=admin works but 
http://localhost:81/?q=admin/content does not. When i login it redirects me to "/admin/content" which 404's

Comment: Just installed an htaccess file
- I uncommented  "RewriteBase /" from the htaccess. 
- I have enabled "mod_rewrite"

but i can get to http://localhost:81/?q=admin/

but not 

http://localhost:81/?q=admin/content

basically i can't login to edit the niceurl

Answer (score 2):

Just had this same problem. Here's what worked for me:

> If localhost/example/admin is not working...
>
> Symptom: I can not access the administration page of my website
>   (admin/ link). Server: localhost with wamp or easy php OS: windows xp
>
> This problem with Drupal 6 is due to the fact that Check Update module
>   is available by default. This module always try to check update from
>   Internet (at the Drupal module website) each time that I click to the
>   admin site link.
>
> To disable the Check Update module without any possible connection on
>   admin site page, go to your mySQL database page and select system
>   table. Select the record which filename
>   field="modules/update/update.module". Change the value of status field
>   to 0.
>
> Thus, the admin page of my drupal website is now accessible.
>
> Under Mac OS X, this problem does not exist.

Source: http://www.ambohimalaza.org/perso/?q=article/drupal-6-admin-link-not-accessible-localhost-solution

Comment: My problem presented the same way and was fixed by disabling the update module (it can be easier to use drush: `drush pm-disable update --y`)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue recently.. Check your 'variables' table in the database for any references to the server path, chances are you'll have to update them to reflect the new path ( for example from /home/mySite/ to C:/wamp/www/mySite/ ).

Also worth trying: truncating all the cache tables and can you get to the login prompt via http://localhost/mySite/user/login ?